# Parametrized types in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, parameterized-constructor

I have searched for some time and I can't find a solution. It's probably a simple syntax issue that I can't figure out.

I have a type:

```
# type ('a, 'b) mytype = 'a * 'b;;
```

And I want to create a variable of type `string string sum`.

```
# let (x:string string mytype) = ("v", "m");;
Error: The type constructor mytype expects 2 argument(s),
   but is here applied to 1 argument(s)
```

I've tried different way of putting parenthesis around type parameters, I get pretty much the same error.

It works, however, with single parameter types so I guess there's some syntax I don't know.

```
# type 'a mytype2 = string * 'a;;
# let (x:string mytype2) = ("hola", "hello");;
val x : string mytype2 = ("hola", "hello")
```

Can someone, please, tell me how to do this with two parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write

```
let (x: (string, string) mytype) = ("v", "m");;
```

That is `mytype` parameter is a couple. You can even remove unneeded parentheses:

```
let x: (string, string) mytype = "v", "m";;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that your type `mytype` is just a *synonym* for a pair, since it doesn't have any constructors. So you can just say `let x = ("v", "m")`.

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.01.0

# type ('a, 'b) mytype = 'a * 'b;;
type ('a, 'b) mytype = 'a * 'b
# let x = ("v", "m");;
val x : string * string = ("v", "m")
# (x : (string, string) mytype);;
- : (string, string) mytype = ("v", "m")
```

The point is that the two types `string * string` and `(string, string) mytype` are the same type.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not using it this way, I was just trying to figure out how to create something of a parametrized type. The pair *synonym* is just a simple example of such a type.